# How to add wrapper to article teaser content

Tags: theming

I need to add a wrapper around the title, body, id, and created fields of the teaser below but am not familiar with how to implement this in a twig template. I need to have the image in a seperate container from the rest of the content:

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I theme the teaser?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/222497/how-do-i-theme-the-teaser)

Comment: hello - you can use module https://www.drupal.org/project/field_group and on teaser display mode put those fields together. You don't need to use twig in this case

Comment: Display Suite (https://www.drupal.org/project/ds) is another venerable module that makes it easy to do this sort of thing. Also, you might want to look at the newer layout builder options.